# How to store two fields in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

well i am storing An id of a student into a NSMUtableArray what i am trying is that to expand that array to accept two field rather than just the student id

> ```
> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
> NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]];
> if (archivedArray == nil) {
>
>     data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];         
> } else {
>     data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:archivedArray];
> }
> ```

As you can see the data variable is only expecting one field

Comment: If you want to have more than one item in the array, then you can add items to data using `-addObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have two (or more, later) fields for each "record" in the array.

One common way to do that could be to create a dictionary with the fields you need, then add the dictionaries to the array:

```
NSDictionary *student1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"key1", @"id",
                          @"Joe", @"name",
                          nil];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:student1, nil];
```

Feel free to add more fields to the student record, and more students to the array. The id field of the dictionary maybe shouldn't be a string, either, but that'll do for a start.

Comment: Generic containers (NSDictionary) are useful for generic things, but since a "Student" seems to be a primary model object in your app, you should seriously consider making a Student class with the needed properties.